# SQL: ALIAS, INNER JOIN not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, inner-join, alias

I'm doing a school project where i need to do following in asp.net:

**Make a list of photoalbums with the number of images in each album.**

I keep getting an error when i try to open the page in my browser (Chrome/Windows):

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'Album'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near 'Album'.

I suspect it has something to do with the SelectCommand and INNER JOIN.

My database has 2 tables: "Album" and "Billeder" (which means images in danish).

The table **"Album"** has following columns:

- Id
- navn *(name)*
- oprettetDen *(Date created)*
- redigeretDen *(Date Edited)*

The table **"Billeder"** has the following columns:

- Id
- imgnavn *(image name)*
- thumbnavn *(thumbnail image name)*
- alt *(image text)*
- oprettetDen *(Date created)*
- redigeretDen *(Date Edited)*
- fkAlbumId *(Foreign key Id for **"Album"**-table)*

Here is my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataAlbums" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT Billeder.imgnavn AS billede Album.navn AS albums FROM [Billeder] INNER JOIN Album ON Album.Id = Billeder.fkAlbumId"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Navn</th>
        <th>Antal billeder i Albummet</th>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterAlbums" DataSourceID="SqlDataAlbums" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval ("albums") %></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a comma between `Billeder.imgnavn AS billede` and `Album.navn AS albums`

```
SELECT Billeder.imgnavn AS billede, Album.navn AS albums 
FROM [Billeder] INNER JOIN Album ON Album.Id = Billeder.fkAlbumId
```

Comment: ... next time I'm going to answer before fixing the post lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` statement is missing a comma:

```
SELECT Billeder.imgnavn AS billede Album.navn
```

should be

```
SELECT Billeder.imgnavn AS billede, Album.navn
```